# SCRAPY - XPATH select a object inside a node

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I need to get an object inside a variable inside a node which is a javascript node.
(Using scrapy 1.8.0 didn't update yet hehe)

Maybe I don't explain myself clearly but as soon you see it... you will understand.

```
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script id='myscript'>
      oneVariable = {...}
      theVariable = {"Data": "blahblah", "More-Data": {...}}
  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Ok I got the whole node with his information manually using `scrapy shell` and then the selector

`response.xpath('//*[@id="myscript"]').get()`

Can I get the "theVariable" I want just with XPATH selectors or functions (like get(), getAll() etc)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing you xpath expression to something like:

```
substring-after(//script[@id="myscript"],"theVariable = ")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it this evening!